# Sliding a animated div back if user click on body

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-animate

I'm creating a feedback form. The description of the problem is given below

I want that the div should slide back, when a use click on the `body` anywhere and also on **contact Us**. I've tried like this.

```
$(document).click(function () {
    $('div.slider').animate({
        toggle: "width"
    }, 1000, function () {

    });
});
```

but in this case the div is sliding back and forth when I'm trying to `click` over that. 
I googled around but the thing where i stuck around is how to search means which *keyword* is describing my problem
I don't want this.
Adding a link to my code in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kaushikkishore/cQswC/5/).

---

Answer to this question is given by [Pete](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1790982/pete)
Thank You Pete
Link to [Fiddle is Here](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/cQswC/11/)

Comment: adding the event to the document click means that it will fire if you click anywhere on your document - including in your form, you either need to unbind the document click when your form is showing and then rebind it when it is hidden, or bind the click event to something else that doesn't encompass the whole document (which would be the better solution as in it's current form, any link clicks will also make the form popup)

Comment: Thank you @Pete yeah I got your point, But I want to know how can i do that in `coding` way ?

Comment: Perhaps when you open your slider, you can add a masque that sits behind the slider but covers the whole screen that you could then bind the click event to: [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/cQswC/10/)

Comment: @Pete it is not working properly, when I'm clicking back on the body area, the slider is open, that should not happen. That is the part to which I'm struggling around. It should not open when user again click on body. I should work only for close.

Comment: [try this one](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/cQswC/11/)

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/cQswC/12/

Comment: @Pete example looks better but you have to add extra element to the page.

Comment: @Aamir, nice use of stopPropogation - I was trying to think how to use that

Comment: Answered the question with solution. Acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the script that will work for you: http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/cQswC/12/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var animation = "155px";
$('div.right, .slider').click(function(e){e.stopPropagation();});
$('div.right').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).animate({
        right:animation
    },200,function(){
        if(animation === "155px")
            animation = "-40px";
        else
            animation = "155px";
        console.log("Animation Complete");
    });
    $('div.slider').animate({
        width:"toggle"
    },200, function(){
        console.log("Slider Animation Complter");
    });
});

//catch the event and check if element clicked is not the toggle label
$('html').click(function (e) {
    if(animation =='155px') return;
    if (!$('.right').is($(e.target))) {
        $('.right').click();
    }
});
```

});